# How to make a linked-list from a binary tree (pre/post order)

Tags: c, linked-list, binary-tree, preorder, postorder

I have looked through a few questions but I can't seem to figure out what is going on. I am trying to convert my binary tree into a linked list that is in either pre/post order. My code is returning a linked list composed of zeros. I excluded the code for post-order as it is essentially the same as pre in this instance. Here is my relevant code:

```
typedef struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
} List;

List* createNode(int data)
{
    // create node in memory
    List* list = malloc(sizeof(list));
    // init parameters
    list->data = data;
    list->next = NULL;
}

void printList(List *list)
{
    //if(list->next == NULL) printf("y");
    while(list != NULL) {
        printf("%d", list->data);
        list = list->next;
    }
}

void preOrder(node *tree, List *list)
{   
    if(tree == NULL) return;
    // visit root
    list = createNode(tree->data);
    // left
    preOrder(tree->left, list->next);
    // right
    preOrder(tree->right, list->next);
}

int preL(node *a)
{
    // create preList
    List *preList = malloc(sizeof(List));
    preOrder(a,preList);
    printList(preList);
}
```

Comment: Before anyone asks I have looked through the other 3 questions regarding this, they were not helpful in the slightest.

Comment: More significantly, what’s in your MCVE ([MCVE]]) and it’s main function?  What sample data are you using?  What do you expect?  Where’s your code to print the tree?  Have you shown that the tree is properly constructed?  What’s the node structure look like?  Is the tree intact after “conversion” to a list?

Comment: Ah it has to be complete and functioning? Let me restructure it into something that works and makes a little more sense

Answer (score 0):

Your function allocates only nodes but never returns them to the caller.  I would write it like:

```
void slist_add(struct list *head, struct list **root)
{
     head->next = *root;
     *root = head;
}

struct list **preOrder(node *tree, List **list)
{   
    struct list *node;

    if (tree == NULL)
        return list;

    node = createNode(tree->data);
    slist_add(node, list);

    list = &list->next;    
    list = preOrder(tree->left, list);
    list = preOrder(tree->right, list);

    return list;
}
```

and call it as

```
List *preList = NULL;
preOrder(a, &preList);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some errors at understanding how lists works:

1. `list*` is a pointer to the **first** element in list and *only to the first element*
2. When adding an element to the tail of the list you should loop the list in order to add the element to the back of the list. That means that you **must** update `list->next`

   - In your pre order code you are not updating the next pointer of newly created `list`.
   - You are essentially overriding your `list` *variable* with a new node, loosing all other nodes processed until then.

The above method is not efficient because each time we insert a note we must pass all the nodes in the list.

Modified code:

```
void insertList(List *list,List *element)
{
    while(list->next != NULL) {
        printf("%d", list->data);
        list = list->next;
    }
    list->next=element;
}
void preOrder(node *tree, List *list)
{   
    if(tree == NULL) return;
    // visit root
    // the new element
    List *element = createNode(tree->data);
    //insert to the tail of the list
    insertList(list,element);
    // left
    // pass the initial list with the head inserted
    preOrder(tree->left, list);
    // right
    // pass the initial list with the head inserted and the left tree nodes
    preOrder(tree->right, list);
}

int preL(node *a)
{
    // create preList
    List *preList = malloc(sizeof(List));
    preOrder(a,preList);
    printList(preList);
}
```

In order to make the code **efficient** you must **NOT** loop the list every time you insert an element. 
Try to do it yourself!(*Hint: you can keep a pointer to the last element*:) ).